# Anchored Smooth Scroll Script jumping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to implement a smooth scroll with JS but all I'm getting from the anchored points is a sharp jump, not a smooth transition. Here is the code, I'm pretty certain I've got the syntax right, although evidently not, as it's not working. The two elements I'm trying to link, plus the script.

```
  <div id="crumbs1">
   <a href="#anchor1"></a>
   </div>


'<div class="poem">
<div id="poem-list1">
<a href="/Crows">Black Crows</a>
<a name="anchor1" id="anchor1"></a>
</div>'

`$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what JS files are included or called in your HTML? jquery? jquery ui?

Comment: can you put your code in a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Jquery is in `<head>` @MarceloBezerra, but the script itself is also in the head not a local file, here is the jfiddle, background images missing (things generally a bit messy, but JS problem the main thing), top button link on the left should scroll from anywhere to top link on right. http://jsfiddle.net/w11wsh98/2/

Comment: Try `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the browser jumping to target

Answer (score 0):

If you don't (absolutly) have to use anchors (and you can control the IDs), you could try something like:

(html)

```
<div id="q1" class="question"><p id="p1" class="dp1">Anchor 1</p></div>
<div id="q2" class="question"><p id="p2" class="dp2">Anchor 2</p></div>
<div id="q3" class="question"><p id="p3" class="dp3">Anchor 3</p></div>

<div id="r1" class="result"><p id="" class="">Response 1</p></div>
<div id="r2" class="result"><p id="" class="">Response 2</p></div>
<div id="r3" class="result"><p id="" class="">Response 3</p></div>
```

and
(script)

```
$('div[id*=q]').click(function () {

var $this = $(this).attr('id');
var $nmb = $this.substr(1);
var $target = 'r' + $nmb;

    if ($target.length) {

        var $target = '#' + $target;
        var thisTarget = $($target).offset().top;

        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: thisTarget
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }

});
```